# Argparse with multiple subparsers in one command

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I want to be able to achieve something like this:

'python program host add 192.168.1.1'

'python program host remove 192.168.1.1'

I don't know how to properly code 'add' or 'remove' subparser.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

host_cmd = subparsers.add_parser('host')
host_cmd.set_defaults(func=host)
add_cmd.add_argument('add', dest='add')
```

I want to be able to read the variable that the user pass in (in this case, 192.168.1.1).

Comment: use `argparse` and when you get error message then come back to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current code you can create only `host --add 192.168.1.1` but it is much simpler code.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='parser')

host_cmd = subparsers.add_parser('host')

host_cmd.add_argument('--add')
host_cmd.add_argument('--remove')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if args.parser == 'host':
    if args.add is not None:
        print('add host:', args.add)
    if args.remove is not None:
        print('remove host:', args.remove)
```

You need subparser in subparser - `host add 192.168.1.1`

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='parser')

host_cmd = subparsers.add_parser('host')

host_subparsers = host_cmd.add_subparsers(dest='parser_host')

host_add_cmd = host_subparsers.add_parser('add')
host_add_cmd.add_argument('ip')

host_remove_cmd = host_subparsers.add_parser('remove')
host_remove_cmd.add_argument('ip')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if args.parser == 'host':
    if args.parser_host == 'add':
        print('add host:', args.ip)
    elif args.parser_host == 'remove':
        print('remove host:', args.ip)
```

---

**EDIT:** example for `host add port 80` but there is conflict with `host add 192.168.1.1` so I removed it

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='parser')

host_cmd = subparsers.add_parser('host')

host_subparsers = host_cmd.add_subparsers(dest='parser_host')

host_add_cmd = host_subparsers.add_parser('add')
#host_add_cmd.add_argument('ip')

add_subparsers = host_add_cmd.add_subparsers(dest='parser_add')

host_add_port_cmd = add_subparsers.add_parser('port')
host_add_port_cmd.add_argument('add_port')


host_remove_cmd = host_subparsers.add_parser('remove')
host_remove_cmd.add_argument('ip')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if args.parser == 'host':
    if args.parser_host == 'add':
        if args.parser_add == 'port':
            print('add port', args.add_port)
    elif args.parser_host == 'remove':
        print('remove', args.ip)
```

Comment: Hey furas, say if I wanted to branch off from 'add'. For example: 'python program host add port 88' - I tried to add a subparser of add, but I'm not getting it right... add_subparsers = host_add_cmd.add_subparsers(dest='parser_add')
host_add_port_cmd = add_subparsers.add_parser('add')
host_add_port_cmd.add_argument('port')

Comment: I added example for `host add port 80` but there is conflict with `host add 192.168.1.1` and both can't work together. It makes too complicate. I would use `--port`